# Can I use debians `dch` / `devscripts` on a macOS to build a debian package?

Tags: macos, debian, packaging

This might be a very naive question and there might be no solution. But maybe someone had the same problem already:

Currently, in our project, we use something like

```
dch --force-distribution --force-bad-version -m -v "1.2.3" -D jessie "Automatic build"
```

and then

```
debuild -us -uc -b
```

We also use

```
debsign -k "123" "${CHANGES_FILE}"
dput my-debian "${CHANGES_FILE}"
```

We have a `debian` folder with nescessary information as for example the `changelog` file.

Is it possible to somehow do all that on a `macOS` machine? Or will I have to install a virtual linux machine?

I’ve seen that there is a `dpkg` for `macOS` installed via `brew install dpkg` but how to do that distribution and versioning with `dpkg` ?
Is that even possible?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think it's impossible to make these tools run on MacOS, but you have to look out for the entire dependency chain. In particular, all the general Unix tools like `sed`, `grep`, `find` etc are GNU versions with significant extensions on Debian; you will have to make sure you install the GNU tools on MacOS as well, and make them take precedence over the system-supplied *BSD versions. The GNU versions have significant extensions which are not portable to MacOS or generally non-GNU systems.

Comment: Ok I see :(
Thank you for taking the time to answer my question!

Comment: Yeah that might be a good workaround. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried it. That is the most simple and quickest solution. Thanks. Sad that the tools are not available on macOS

Comment: Like I wrote, it's probably not impossible to pull off, but piecing together an isolated environment with all the dependencies is probably much more challenging than building a corresponding Docker image. Please be invited to share your implementation in an actual answer!

Comment: just for completenessreasons: dch is a perl script, dput seems to be python3, debsign is a bashscript that uses gpg